# Hide specific post on wordpress mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I've got a blog/website running on a wordpress installation and one of the posts does not display properly on the mobile version of the site.  I was wondering if there was any way to hide a particular post whether through CSS or jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: A link to the site maybe?

Comment: http://inkgeniusblog.co.uk

I want to hide the last post with the swatchbook because it doesn't display correctly on mobile devices.

Comment: you could use the id of the div to to display none on a media query which checks for small screen sizes. But it probably just worth fixing what ever the issue is on mobile.

Comment: I would do that but it's really not worth the hassle of trying to make the content of the iframe responsive so would rather just hide it for mobile users.  It's only a simple thing about social networks which if they're accessing on a mobile devices they've probably landed there from a social network anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can inspect the site with firebug you can see that every post has one unique id like "id='post-87'" you can go to css and write below code to hide it.

```
#post-87{
  display:none;
}
```

This is not preferable solution but you can do it if you want to do it static.

**For Mobile:**

Use media query as below:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #post-87{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

You can change width 600px to whatever you want. it will be work on below 600px resolution devices. You can define any number of media query as i show you above.

Comment: I would do that however I still want to be able to view it on computers/laptops but not on mobile devices?  I'm not overly familiar with media queries

Comment: Check my edited answer. you will able to do it for mobile devices as i mentioned.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but just tried this putting it with the other responsive code and changing the id to match the post I'm trying to hide and it isn't working.

Comment: Try to keep it at bottom in your css file first. then try "display:none!important;" add !important will make it force to do it. Also check whether you are below 600px resolution or not? First check by resizing your browser if it works then it will work in mobile too.

Comment: Adding the !important worked spot on! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code at the end of your page just before <`/body> tag:

`<script>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#id-of-your-post").hide();
});
```

`</script>`

Comment: Using jQuery just to hide it, seems a bit overkill?

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what Tom said:

Using CSS to hide a post from certain user agents might *appear* to be a valid solution, but will actually break your site in various annoying ways:

1. The hidden post will still be visible to search engines.
2. Wordpress will also still behave as if the post exists. So for example, the user will still see a link for "December 2013" in the side bar, even though it leads to an inexplicably empty page. The same applies to the category, tag, author and search result pages.
3. The post will still appear in the site's [RSS](http://inkgeniusblog.co.uk/?feed=rss), [RDF](http://inkgeniusblog.co.uk/?feed=rdf) [and](http://inkgeniusblog.co.uk/?feed=rss2) [Atom](http://inkgeniusblog.co.uk/?feed=atom) feeds, so you'll be sending broken links to your subscribers.

I'm not aware of any simple way of hiding a post while avoiding all of these problems, except perhaps creating a mirror of the entire site without this particular post in it.

It would be far better to simply fix this post so that it works on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

further expansion on tom & squeamish ossifrage have said : keep the post but try changing the template 
here is a WP thread that might help: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/applying-templates-to-custom-post-types
and a WP plugin : http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/

Comment: It may be me being daft but I'm not sure how this would help in my situation?  All I'm trying to do is hide a post when viewed on a mobile device.  Basically the post contains an iFrame of a page that had a jQuery swatch book.  due to the nature of the content I'm not going to work for ages making the contents responsive.  As far as the viewing in the RSS feed and the Archives section is concerned I'm not overly fussed there will be numerous posts per month anyways and the post will still be there if they come from google (assuming they're on a mobile device)

Comment: it would help if you will have more posts like that (eg - anything you want to hide/change display on mobile). it also relates to viken's answer, which solved your problem :)